# PHP - avconv create thumbnail wrong rotation

Tags: php, avconv

In my server I am using `avconv` library in order to generate thumbnails from videos. The call works fine except that the image generated got rotated by 90 degrees.

Here the call:

```
shell_exec("avconv -itsoffset -4  -i $video -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 400x244 $thumbnail");
```

How can I remove the rotation in order to get the exact image orientation?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the transpose video filter. You cannot rotate by 180 degrees, but you can rotate by 90 degrees and chain the filter.

avconv -i video.mp4 -vf transpose=1,transpose=1 out.mkv

See transpose in the avconv manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/en/man1/avconv.1.html